# lookup edit cannot scroll

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

in my lookup edit , when the mouse is in the item list , i cant scroll it
[image]

also i cant scroll it outside of from the lookup edit

[image]

the funny thing is i can scroll it when my cursor is in this place
[image]

how do i overcome this ?
and then when i try to goto pc setting i inactive this setting

[image]

i can scroll whereever i want. is there any code to disable this setting ?

iam using devexpress.ver 12 and ms.studio ver 15 and windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it is not already set to true:

```
lookUpEditControl.Properties.AllowMouseWheel = true;
```